# PHP, no me guarda la información en la BD MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

estoy creando un formulario en php con html y al momento de querer guardar el formulario en la base de datos no se guarda nada, me genera el registro (me doy cuenta por que tengo un ID autoincremental), pero la información que guardo en el formulario no aparece. Estos son mis códigos:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="reg.php">
  <p>Registro</p>
  <p>
    <label>Nickname           
    <input name="nickName" type="text" id="nick" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Nombre
del usuario   
<input name="nombreUsuario" type="text" id="nombre_usuario" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Contraseña
    <input name="passUsuario" type="password" id="contrasena"  />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Repetir contraseña 
    <input name="RpassUsuario" type="password" id="RpassUsuario"  />
    </label>
</p>
  <p>
    <label></label>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

reg.php:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$conexion=mysqli_connect("*******","******","*****","*****") or die("Problemas con la conexión");
         mysqli_query($conexion,"insert into tabla_usuarios (id_usuario,nick,nombre_usuario,contrasena)values ('','$_POST[nick]','$_POST[nombre_usuario]','$_POST[contrasena]')")or die("problemas con el select");

         mysqli_close($conexion);
         echo "<br><br> los datos fueron guardados <br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

La tabla_usuarios tienen las columnas:
id_usuario
nick
nombre_usuario
contrasena

Necesito ayuda por favor :(

Comment: por que en `VALUES` pones unas comillas vacías?

Comment: es el valor autoincremental

Comment: no @Ana Mendoza, si tienes una llave primaria; entonces quita `id_usuario` y también esas comillas, no es necesario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando en tu base de datos declaras una columna con las siguientes características:

- `PRIMARY KEY`
- `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- Cuando vas a leer los valores por medio de PHP, a través de `$_POST[]` debes colocar el nombre de la etiqueta `name` para que te de este modo pueda leer el valor que ahi fue ingresado

No es necesario declarar ni la columna ni mucho menos un valor asociado a ella; entonces  puedes declarar tu query del modo siguiente

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect("*******","******","*****","*****") or die("Problemas con la conexión"); 
mysqli_query($conexion,"insert into tabla_usuarios (nick,nombre_usuario,contrasena) 
            values ('$_POST[nick]','$_POST[nombreUsuario]','$_POST[passUsuario]')")
or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Por otro lado deberías de considerar trabajar con sentencias preparadas, pues como esta ahorita tu query es vulnerable a ataques de sql injection

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect("*******","******","*****","*****") or die("Problemas con la conexión"); 
$alta = $conexion->prepare("insert into tabla_usuarios (nick,nombre_usuario,contrasena) 
            values (?, ?, ?)");
$alta->bind_param("sss", $_POST[nick], $_POST[nombreUsuario], $_POST[passUsuario]);
$alta->execute();

echo "Agregado con éxito";

$alta->close();

?>
```

Comment: Al momento de ponerlo así me marca el error "Problemas con el select"

Comment: @AnaMendoza por favor dale editar a tu pregunta y añade una descripción de las columnas que componen a tu tabla

Comment: @AnaMendoza por otro lado al momento de leer los valores por medio de `$_POST[]` se debe poner el valor que pusiste en la etiqueta `name` y tenias un par de errores pues en uno pusiste el valor pero de la etiqueta id

Comment: ya los cambie y me sigue mandando el mismo error

Comment: @AnaMendoza añade esto al final de tu query para que muestre cual error esta ocurriendo `mysqli_query($conexion,"insert into tabla_usuarios 
                           (nick,nombre_usuario,contrasena) values 
('$_POST[nick]','$_POST[nombreUsuario]','$_POST[passUsuario]')")or die(mysqli_error($conexion));`

Comment: muchas gracias, ya se solucionó el problema !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes una clave primaria autoincrementable es mejor no llamarla en el select ni darle un valor. El gestor de base de datos se encarga de asignarle el valor correspondiente a la sucesión de números que ya existe. Como te aconsejan todos, cambia esto:

```
"insert into tabla_usuarios (id_usuario,nick,nombre_usuario,contrasena)values ('','$_POST[nick]','$_POST[nombre_usuario]','$_POST[contrasena]')"
```

por esto:

```
"insert into tabla_usuarios (nick,nombre_usuario,contrasena)values ('$_POST[nick]','$_POST[nombre_usuario]','$_POST[contrasena]')"
```